# MVC ActionResult - Nullable or Optional parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nullable, optional-parameters, pagedlist

When passing a page number to my MVC action for a paged list, it's not required to supply a page number. If no page number is selected the number defaults to the first page.
Most of the documentation for this seems to favour the use of the null coalescing operator, e.g.

```
Public ActionResult Demo(int? page)
{
    const int pageSize = 10
    var model _db.Model.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, pageSize);
    return View(model);
}
```

Or something similar.

I'm wondering if there is a benefit of using this over using default parameters, e.g.

```
Public ActionResult Demo(int page = 1)
{
    const int pageSize = 10
    var model _db.Model.ToPagedList(page, pageSize);
    return View(model);
}
```

Or even

```
Public ActionResult Demo(int? page = 1)
{
    const int pageSize = 10
    var model _db.Model.ToPagedList(page.Value, pageSize);
    return View(model);
}
```

Though having page as  a nullable type in this instance seems redundant.

Is there any benefit of using one of these methods in particular or is it just syntactic sugar.

Edit: Fixed null exception in third example

Comment: As for the last option I wouldn't say redundant but wrong - because if they pass `null` that is what `page` will be equal to and you will probably get an exception from the `ToPagedList` method

Comment: AFAIK 1) _Old_ way before optional parameters were supported. Still required when logic is more complex than a simple constant value. Also needed if constant value is decided in a called function and you need to _propagate_ the null 2) Common way if there isn't a way for the client to say "use defaults" but still send the parameter 3) If you need a way for the client to say "use default" and send the parameter. 2/3 are often equivalent but _sentinel_ values can be harmful if used too much...

Comment: Also for the last option you'd have to use `page.Value`, unless `.ToPagedList` happens to use `int?` for its 1st parameter.

Comment: Addendum: note that "int? page" will also handle the case where parameter value is _invalid_ while "int page" will just throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last one doesn't make sense `Public ActionResult Demo(int? page = 1)`.

Based on your scenario, first two action methods won't make any different since the parameter is for page number. *People expect to land on a first page if no parameter is supplied.*

However, you do not want to use optional parameter for if you care about the value.

```
public ActionResult UserDetails(int? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue)
        return View("UserNotFound"); // Or return a message.

    int userId = id.Value; 
    var user = _userService.GetUserById(userId);
    // Do something
}
```

You cannot use optional parameter in above scenario - `public ActionResult UserDetails(int id = 123)`

***FYI:*** You do not want to use `public ActionResult UserDetails(int id)`. It'll cause a crash if id is not supplied.